# How to present guest Wi-Fi "terms & conditions" confirmation dialog programmatically?

Tags: ios, wifi

It is typical setup in bars / restaurants / airports where password-free Wi-Fi is available but requires accepting terms & conditions.

First time customer manually connects to Wi-Fi network which brings confirmation dialog and he accepts it. As result internet connection is alive, no problem here.
However next time customer visits the same place iOS device automatically connects to the known Wi-Fi and shows active Wi-Fi connection icon in status bar. But internet connection isn't available until customer accepts terms & conditions again. To do that customer has to either go to iOS settings or open Safari which brings confirmation dialog automatically.

Our app is designed for bars. Based on above iOS behavior regular customer sees that it has Wi-Fi connection in iPhone status bar, yet our app says "No internet connection". Combined this is very confusing UX.

Question: Is there programatic way to bring Wi-Fi confirmation dialog the same way as Safari does?

Comment: Captive portals typically serve that page in response to any HTTP request; you can simply load any non-HTTPS URL.

Comment: iOS should do this automatically if your captive portal is configured correctly.  When it connects to a WiFi network, iOS checks to see if `http://captive.apple.com` returns "success".  If it does then it assumes that it has Internet access.  If it returns any other content then it assumes that there is a captive portal and it will open the captive portal authentication screen.  The behaviour is independent of whether the user has connected to that hotspot previously.

Comment: Where there can be an issue is when the hotspot de-authenticates the user after some time as iOS does not continually re-try captive.apple.com once it has connected successfully.  Your app can periodically check captive.apple.com returns the correct response and open an `SFSafariViewController` if it doesn't,

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, solution with checking `http://captive.apple.com` and bringing `SFSafariViewController` makes sense. Feel free to post it as an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS should do this automatically if your captive portal is configured correctly.

When it connects to a WiFi network, iOS checks to see if http://captive.apple.com returns "success". If it does then it assumes that it has Internet access. If it returns any other content then it assumes that there is a captive portal and it will open the captive portal authentication screen.

This behaviour is independent of whether the user has connected to that hotspot previously.

Where there can be an issue is when the hotspot de-authenticates the user after some time, as iOS does not continually re-try http://captive.apple.com once it has connected successfully.

Your app can periodically check that http://captive.apple.com returns the correct response and open an `SFSafariViewController` if it doesn't